# Grails createCriteria many-to-many

Tags: grails, criteria

Imagine i have the following (this is a search mechanism for my website)

```
class Supermarket {    
String sp_name
String sp_street
}

class Products {
String p_name
String p_price
}

class products_supermarket{
Supermarket sp
Products pro
}
```

Now i want to create a criteria:

```
def c = Supermarket.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    like("sp_street", params.street)
    and {
        ************ ... params.product
    }
    maxResults(10)

}
```

Where i have the *** i want to be able to find products whithin that supermaked searching on products_supermarket class. How to do that?

PS. If criteria works as an each() method, iterating over all supermarkets, i could use an if-else statment to search for products, and if found i could use: ***idEq(it)***, where **it** is the supermarket id. This way i would make it. My problem is, i dont know how to get current'sm supermarket id. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `and` is applied to criterias **inside** it, so there's no point applying it to a single statement. Top-level criterias are `and`-ed by defauilt.
2. You usually better go without connector class, just by using `hasMany: Supermarket` and `hasMany: Product` in domain classes. Connector table will be auto-generated by Hibernate.
3. If you stick with `ProductsSupermarket` connector class, do add `belongsTo: Supermarket` and `belongsTo: Product` to it class, and add 'hasMany: ProductsSupermarket' to other two, or you're losing Grails' GORM advantage.
4. There's a section ["Querying Associations" in the doc](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest//guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.4.1%20Dynamic%20Finders).
5. Object's `id` is as simple as that: `mySupermarket.id`, or `mySupermarket.ident()` if key field is named differently. `id` field is auto-added to class and table by default.

So the query is:

```
List<Supermarket> results = Supermarket.withCriteria {
    like("sp_street", params.street)
    productSupermarket {
        product {
            idEq(params.product)
        }
        // or just eq('product', someProduct)
    }
    ************ ... params.product
    maxResults(10)
}
```